# q_property with enum from another class (defined with q_enum) in qt designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I create custom widget, that I used in qt designer plugin:

```
class InfoItemWithLineEdit final : public QWidget, public Ui::InfoItemWithLineEdit {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QLineEdit::EchoMode echoMode READ echoMode WRITE setEchoMode)
...
};
```

all works fine (it compiles, works at runtime, if I add such lines

```
 <property name="echoMode">
  <enum>QLineEdit::Password</enum>
 </property>
```

into .ui file, uic generate valid code.

But, I can not edit property in Qt Designer (plugin loaded fine,
all other properties of `InfoItemWithLineEdit` works fine),
but for exactly this property, qt designer reports to console:

```
QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QLineEdit::EchoMode' for property 'InfoItemWithLineEdit::echoMode'
```

and does not show `echoMode` property in property list.

Any hints how can I reuse `QLineEdit::EchoMode` properly?

Comment: provide a [mcve], please

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to provide a `Q_ENUM(QLineEdit::EchoMode)` yourself (in `InfoItemWithLineEdit`).